# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - Replace a value in arraylist using element name not index

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I'm trying to change the name of an element inside my Arraylist without index.

I have an array below:

```
 ArrayList<String> testArr = new ArrayList<String>();
 notInstSfw.add(s);
 notInstSfw.add(s);
 notInstSfw.add(s);
```

(s - values from another array)

Is there any chance to replace the name of the Computer1 without using index?

Because I don't know which index refers to a particular value.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems there are some pieces missing.  Perhaps you could provide some additional information to better define your problem.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use `ArrayList`? There are other options that do exactly this (use name not index) more efficiently, e.g. `HashSet`. Unless you have duplicate names or use index elsewhere in your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get an index of the element you want to change/replace.

```
int find(List<String> l, String str){
  for(int i = 0, String s: l, i++)
    if (s.equals(str)) return i;
  return -1;
}
int ind;
if ((ind = find(testArr, "some")) != -1)
  testArr.set(ind, "other")
```

Searching into the list has a complexity O(n). Until your array is not sorted and you can calculate an index from the value you can keep this solution.